# I tried installing the ssh_package into my ubuntu 16.04 but it is giving me this error. I am running ubuntu on VMWare workstation pro

Tags: ssh, hadoop

```
rmehra@ubuntu:~/Desktop/ssh_package$ sudo dpkg -i openssh-client_1%3a5.3p1-3ubuntu7_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 172254 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack openssh-client_1%3a5.3p1-3ubuntu7_i386.deb ...
Unpacking openssh-client:i386 (1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7) over (1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-client:i386:
 openssh-client:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.11).
 openssh-client:i386 depends on libedit2 (>= 2.5.cvs.20010821-1).
 openssh-client:i386 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.7+dfsg).
 openssh-client:i386 depends on libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8k-1).
 openssh-client:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4).

dpkg: error processing package openssh-client:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-client:i386
rmehra@ubuntu:~/Desktop/ssh_package$
```

Comment: Why are you using `dpkg` with some package instead of `sudo apt-get install ssh`?

Comment: i tried that later but then it gave this error  E: Unable to lock the administration directory /var/lib/dpkg/lock? is this root?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running that:

```
sudo dpkg -r openssh-client
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Comment: tried that but it gave me the error E: Unable to lock the administration directory /var/lib/dpkg/lock? is this root?

Comment: even when i tried to get rid of this problem and used sudo apt-get install openssh-client ,it is still showing dependency errors

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg -r openssh-client` first, then run the apt-get command.

Comment: @anonymous2 Please edit my answer to add that

Comment: Sure...  ???  Mind if I ask why, @CollDue96?